# JHipster startup on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, jhipster, hazelcast, jhipster-registry

After a fresh deployment of our application on a kubernetes cluster we always will end up with a hazelcast network partitioning problem (split brain).

All three replicas starting at the same time. Hazelcast is configured to use the jhipster-registry (i.e. Eureka) for discovery. At the time, the application tries to initialize hazelcast, no instance is registered in the registry which gives us three independet hazelcast nodes.

The documentation says that hazelcast will detect this and merge all my maps. But this does not happen.

BTW

Comment: The automatic hazelcast clustering provided by JHipster only works for Eureka and Consul. If you use only kubernetes native discovery, you would need to set it up yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using Hazelcast Kubernetes discovery plugin:  https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes

This should work out of the box.